# Show that a power series is continuous in its open interval of convergence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $S(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n$ be a power serie with a convergence radius $Rad>0$. Furthermore, let $z_k$ be a sequence converging to $z_0$. Show that if $\vert z_k\vert\le r < Rad \forall k \in {N} $, we have: $$S(z_k)⟶S(z_0)$$

Comment: The problem makes no sense as stated.

Comment: I think you want $r<Rad$.

Comment: want to show that $S(z_k) \longrightarrow S(z_0)$ (converges to), (edited $r<R$)

Comment: I would prefer solving it without an argument involving continuity

Comment: Even though you're trying to prove continuity?

Comment: You really should get rid of $Rad$ and replace it by $R.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(0). You cannot regard or treat an infinite power series as if it is a polynomial. And you prefer an argument not involving continuity,but what you are trying to prove is that  $S(z)$ is continuous for $|z|\leq r.$ You need more info about "the rest" over ALL $z$.

(1).(i).  I dk whether you are familiar with uniform convergence. Let $D\subset \mathbb C$ and let $(f_n:D\to \mathbb C)_{n\in \mathbb N}$ be a sequence of functions such that $(f_n(z))_n$ converges to a value $f(z)$ for each $z\in D.$  Define $$\|f-f_n\|=\sup_{z\in D}\{|f(z)-f_n(z)|\}.$$ (In general this may fail to  be finite.)  We say $(f_n)_n$ converges uniformly to $f$ iff $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\|f-f_n\|=0.$$

(1).(ii). Suppose $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f.$  If $(g_n:D\to \mathbb C)_n $is a sequence such that $g_n(z)$ converges to a value $g(z)$ for each $ x \in D, $ and if $\|g-g_n\|\leq \|f-f_n\|$ for all but finitely many $n,$ then $(g_n)_n$ converges uniformly. That may seem obvious,  but we may prove  uniform convergence of $( (g_n)_n$ by finding such $(f_n)_n$ whose uniform convergence is easier to prove.

(2).    The Hadamard Radius Formula:

Let $S=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_{m>n}|a_m|^{1/m} .$  Let $R=1/S$ (with $R=\infty$ if $S=0,$ and vice-versa).If $0<r<R$ the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^n$ converges uniformly on $\{z: |z|\leq r\}.$

Proof: (For $0<R<\infty$ only):

(i). Let $r/R=1-d_r.$ Choose positive $e_r,$ small enough that $(1-d_r)(1+e_r)<1.$  For brevity let $(1-d_r)(1+e_r)=V_r.$ We have $0<V_r<1.$

(ii). There are only finitely many $m$ such that $|a_m|^{1/m}|\geq (1+e)/R.$ (Otherwise, by the def'n of $S$ and $R,$ we would have $1/R=S\geq (1+e_r)/R$). So choose $m_0$ such that $$m>m_0\implies |a_m|^{1/m}<(1+e_r)/R.$$ Then for all $z$ such that $|z|\leq r$ we have $$\forall m>m_0\;(|a_mz^m|\leq (\frac {1+e_r}{R})^m (R(1-d_r))^m=V_r^m. \;).$$

(iii). Now for each $m$ let $f_m(z)=\sum_{j=0}^mV_r^j.$ The function $f_m$ is a constant, and $0<V_r<1,$ so the sequence $(f_m)_m$ converges uniformly  to the constant function $f(z)=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}V_r^m.$ From the preceding paragraph (2)(ii), and from the def'n in (1)(i), we deduce that $$m>m_0\implies\|g_m-g\|\leq \|f_m-f\|$$  $$\text {where }\quad g_m(z)=\sum_{j=0}^ma_jz^j$$ $$\text { and }\quad  g(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_jz^j \quad \text {for }  |z|\leq  r$$ $$\text {and }\quad \|g-g_n\|=\sup_{|z|\leq r}\{|g(z)-g_n(z)\}.$$ So $g_n$ converges uniformly to $g$ on $D=\{z:|z|\leq r\}.$

(3).An important theorem. Let $D\subset \mathbb C$ and let $(g_n:D\to \mathbb C)_n$ be a sequence of  functions  that are continuous on D, and converge uniformly to $g.$ Then $g$ is continuous on $D$.

Proof:  Suppose $(z_j)_{j\in \mathbb N}$ is a sequence in $D$ converging to $z\in D.$ For any $e>0$  take $n$ such that $\|g-g_n\|<e/3.$ This is possible because $\lim_{m\to \infty} \|g-g_m\|=0.$
 Since $g_n$ is continuous on $D,$ there exists $j_0$ such that $\forall j>j_0\;(|g_n(z)-g_n(z_j)|<e/3).$

So for all $j>j_0$  we have $$|g(z)-g(z_j)|=$$ $$=|(g(z)-g_n(z))+(g_n(z)-g_n(z_j))+(g_n(z_j)-g(z_j)|\leq$$ $$\leq |g(z)-g_n(z)|+|g_n(z)-g_n(z_j)|+|g_n(z_j)-g(z_j)|\leq$$ $$\leq \|g-g_n\|+|g_n(z)-g_n(z_j)|+\|g_n-g\|<$$ $$<e/3+e/3+e/3=e.$$  So $(g(z_j))_j$ converges to $g(z).$

(4). With $D=\{z:|z|<r\}$ and $g_n(z)=\sum_{j=0}^na_jz^j$ and with $r,R$ as in your Q, we see  by (2) that $g(z)=\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}$ is the uniform limit of $(g_n)_n$ on D and by (3), $g$ is continuous on $D$.

Answer (score 1):

Alternate approach: First, verify that if $b_n \ge 0$ for all $n$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_nR^n$ converges for some $R >0,$ then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} nb_nr^n$ converges for any $r\in [0,R).$ We'll use that below.

Let $R> 0$ be the radius of convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^n.$  Then $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^n$ converges absolutely for $|z|<R.$ Define $f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^n$ for $|z|<R.$

Suppose $0<r<R$ and $z_k \to z_0,$ with $|z_k|\le r < R$ for all $k.$ Then $|z_0| \le r.$ We wish to show $f(z_k)\to f(z_0).$ We have

$$\tag 1 f(z_k) - f(z_0) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n(z_k^n-z_0^n) =  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n(z_k-z_0)(z_k^{n-1} + z_k^{n-2}z_0 + \cdots + z_kz_0^{n-2} + z_0^{n-1}).$$

Therefore

$$|f(z_k) - f(z_0)| \le  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|a_n||z_k-z_0|n r^{n-1} = |z_k-z_0|\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|a_n|n r^{n-1}$$

From the first paragraph, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|a_n|nr^{n-1}$ converges. Thus we have $|f(z_k) - f(z_0)|$ bounded above by a constant times $|z_k-z_0|.$ Hence $f(z_k) \to f(z_0)$ as desired.